# PHP. How dynamically change page content on HTML select action?

Tags: php

I have this code:

**page.php:**

```
<?php

include ('include.php');

echo = '
<li>
    <select name="selector" class="letter">
        <option value="a" selected="selected">$a</option>
        <option value="b">$b</option>
    </select>
</li>
';

echo = '
<li>
    <select name="a-numbers" class="number a-numbers">
        <option value="$a[1][1]">$a[1][2]</option>
        <option value="$a[2][1]">$a[2][2]</option>
    </select>
    <select name="b-numbers" class="number b-numbers">
        <option value="$b[1][1]">$b[1][2]</option>
        <option value="$b[2][1]">$b[2][2]</option>
    </select>
</li>
';

?>
```

&

**include.php:**

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "a" => array(
        "1" => array("aaa1-value","aaa1-text"),     
            "2" => array("aaa2-value","aaa2-text")      
        ),  
        "b" => array(
            "1" => array("bbb1-value","bbb1-text"),     
            "2" => array("bbb2-value","bbb2-text")      
        )   
    )
);

?>
```

If *`.letter>a`* is selected, *`.a-numbers`* list should be echo-printed; and if *`.letter>b`* is selected, *`.a-numbers`* list should be removed and *`.b-numbers`* should be printed.

Of course, I can create this scenario with JS and CSS `display:none`; however, I can't use `display:none` here. So I have to remove elements from DOM, but I can't.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you able to use javascript here?

Comment: I think, yes. But <select> elements are involved in jQuery plugin action (styling forms), so hide/show function couldn't be use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP cannot dynamically do any of this on it's own. You will need to either use AJAX, which will actually send a request/response back to the server to populate the div.

Or, you will need to load all possible content with the initial request/response and use javascript to dynamically show/hide the divs in question.

You mention in your question that you cannot use display:none, so you may want to look into making an asychronous call back the webserver to populate the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove something from the DOM.  jQuery can do it by using

```
 $.remove("[selector]")
```

Then if you need to add them you can use jquery [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [append](http://api.jquery.com/append).  Such as:

```
$("[selector]").append("<!--escaped HTML-->");
```

Comment: Ok. But once it was removed this way, how I can get it back?

Comment: @YNT If it contained in another element. use append or prepend. If that doesn't work would the css ```visibility: hidden;``` work?  You could possibly store the value in a JS variable before you remove it in case you have to restore it.

Comment: `visibility: hidden;` doesn't work, I tried. I'll investigate in append/prepend, thanks.