# Form refresh after submit

Tags: php, mysql, html

The form below can contains different elements of text fields, drop down and selection boxes, which allows the user to update his profile. The process of updating MySQL fields is being done after form submits.

```
<form method="post">
My Name: <input name="myname" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_MY_NAME']; ?>" /><br />
My Email: <input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_EMAIL']; ?>" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" />

<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // MySQL update
    ;
    ;
    ;
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
  }

// if successfully updated, make form refresh. 
  if($result){
    ;
    ;
    ;
  }
?> 
</form>
```

I want to refresh only the form, so that the user will stay in the same page and will see the changes that he made (i.e. What do I need to put under the comment in the code “if successfully updated, make form refresh”?).

I cannot use `header("location: samepage.php");` because I have too many HTML codes involved in between and before.

Appreciate any help,

Comment: Do you mean you want to submit the form without sending a new HTTP header, thus forcing the page to load? That's called AJAX. There are a LOT of duplicate questions on SO regarding it.

Comment: Yep, you'll need to use JavaScript to accomplish the goal you've described.  PHP alone will not cut it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP. How dynamically change page content on HTML select action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398113/php-how-dynamically-change-page-content-on-html-select-action)

Comment: Is it only a one line code solution with Ajax/ Javascript? Can you please explain more?

Comment: @user131569 you want us to give you a tutorial on how server-side versus client-side scripting works? That's probably not going to happen. Read the post I linked to above.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I found an article: “Simple Ajax , Populate div with data from php file.”  Hope this works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `isset($_POST['submit'])` check to the top.

Your current (intended) process is as follows:

1. Retrieve form data from DB/Session/etc.
2. Display as HTML
3. User submits form
4. Repeat steps 1/2
5. Write data to DB
6. Force refresh
7. Repeat 1/2 again

If you move this check to the top, the process is changed to:

1. Retrieve form data from DB
2. Display as HTML
3. User submits form
4. Write data to DB
5. Repeat 1/2 (it will now retrieve the updated information and display correctly).

This is the absolute simplest way you can do it.  It doesn't take into account Post/Redirect/Get or updating the session so multiple DB reads are unncessary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery AJAX to submit and verify the form then output the result in chosen div element.
More on that available at [nettuts+](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Such helpful. Much wow.

Thankfully I was able to solve this on my own after some intense googling since no one else seemed to have an answer. For anyone looking to accomplish the same thing, all you have to do is add the following code to the "Additional Settings" section of your CF7 form configuration:

**on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/contact';**"

Just replace the URL with the URL of your form page and presto, it'll automatically refresh back to that page when the form is submitted!